# PERCENTILE By Header Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to use PERCENTILE within excel

What I need to do is search the headers for a name and then do the PERCENTILE on that column

Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3

If I want to search for Header 2, it will run the PERCENTILE on that column

how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH within the PERCENTILE, something like the following:

```
=PERCENTILE(INDEX(A2:C10,,MATCH("Header 2",A1:C1,0)),0.2)
```

[image]

<sub>N.B. Perhaps consider using the newer functions `PERCENTILE.EXC` or `PERCENTILE.INC` instead of the older `PERCENTILE`.</sub>